# Groupby a Pandas DataFrame and seperately plot the groups

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I have Data from different rain gauge stations, that I would like to compare in a plot.

```
DM_a 

    InputID TargetID   date_ini   date_end      Distance
0     P1311    P1311 1951-01-01 2015-12-31      0.000000
3     P1311    P3953 1941-01-01 1979-06-30   7423.548814
1     P1311    P1351 1941-01-01 2015-12-31   7981.801363
7     P1311    P4933 1900-01-01 1977-06-30   9196.992987
4     P1311    P4926 1946-01-01 2013-05-13   9241.976520
..      ...      ...        ...        ...           ...
298   P6274    P5409 1931-01-01 2015-12-31   9986.552008
294   P6274    P4294 1979-07-01 2002-10-14  10100.677700
292   P6274    P3454 1951-01-01 2003-12-31  10753.593725
290   P6274    P2209 1931-01-01 2001-12-31  12727.343321
291   P6274    P3449 1951-01-01 2000-12-31  13796.558448

[300 rows x 5 columns]
```

here each Station in my InputID is connected to 10 other Stations, that I would like to compare the InputID with.

I would like to create a function that groups the data by my InputID and creates new DataFrames out of the groups (in this case 30)
The groups I would like to seperately plot and use the used InputID in my title.
So it looks like the following plot:

[Timeframe Data Record for Station x] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvAIv.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

start = DM_a.date_ini.values
end = DM_a.date_end.values
stations_1 = DM_a.TargetID.values

y, x = [mdates.date2num(item) for item in (end[0:9], start[0:9])]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ypos = range(len(y))
ax.barh(ypos, y - x, left=x, height=0.8, align='center')
plt.yticks(range(len(x)), stations_1)
ax.axis('tight')

ax.xaxis_date()
plt.title('Timeframe data records for station {} at Neckar'.format(stations_1[0]))
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Station')
plt.show()
```

Right now I'm simply using the index [0:9] to create the plot for my first Station, but I would like to make it more simple to apply to the other stations as well, plotting them seperately by groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `groupby` as shown below. `key` refers to an `InputID` and `group` corresponds to the dataframe associated with that `key`.

```
df_grouped = DM_a.groupby('InputID')
for key, group in df_grouped:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    start = group.date_ini.values
    end = group.date_end.values
    stations_1 = group.TargetID.values
    y, x = [mdates.date2num(item) for item in (end, start)]
    ypos = range(len(y))
    ax.barh(ypos, y - x, left=x, height=0.8, align='center')
    plt.yticks(range(len(x)), stations_1)
    ax.axis('tight')
    ax.xaxis_date()
    plt.title('Timeframe data records for station {} at Neckar'.format(key))
    plt.xlabel('Year')
    plt.ylabel('Station')    
    plt.show()
```